# Integrate React with Freemarker templates

Tags: reactjs, freemarker, magnolia

I work on a large project built on Magnolia CMS and FreeMarker templates and I want to add React to it. Is it possible to integrate React components and grow gradually until the whole project is React based? I looked for this information but the resources are quite limited in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at this one? https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Developing/SPA-development-and-Magnolia/Mapping-between-Magnolia-and-SPA-components.html#_mapping_between_magnolia_and_reactjs

Basically, you can do the mapping between Reach and Magnolia components as described above.